# Maven dependencies in NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, dependencies, jgrapht

I'm new to Maven and have been trying to use JGraphT as a Maven dependency.
But even after installing it locally, the import lines are not recognized.
Here are few screen-shots -

[This is the project window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C53cy.png)

[This is the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3kpm.png)

On running the program I get this message -

[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxlWT.png)

NetBeans version is 8.2

jdk being used is jdk1.8.0_162.

I have no idea where the problem is.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have much to do with jgrapht, but with importing maven dependencies in netbeans.

Comment: The error refers to the old interface 'UndirectedGraph'. This interface doesn't exist anymore. Seems your maven setup in mixing multiple dependencies (i.e. it gets the old 1.1.0 demo package, and the newer 1.1.1 snapshot package). try cleaning your maven cache and remove all jgrapht dependencies.

Comment: @JorisKinable I executed the goal, dependency:purge-local-repository clean install, but still I get a long list of compile errors like package org.jgrapht does not exist, cannot find symbol etc.

Answer (score 0):

The mvn dependency of jGrapht is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgrapht-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Though I am using it in eclipse.